# Free Editor for NAnt Scripting?

Tags: editor, nant

Is there any Free Editor for NAnt scripting with little bit of intelligence is fine....

nrk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of different editors. There is nant wizard which is free for non commercial use. If these don't work you can always just load the xsd into vs and have intellisense support when editing the build files.

Here is the link: http://nant.sourceforge.net/external.html